# Force Waterfox to delete cookies after closing the Window

Tags: cookies, waterfox

There *used* to be an option in Firefox to delete cookies after closing a tab/window. That is not present in the latest version of Waterfox.

Someone I know wants to *have* to sign in each time they open Waterfox and I'm trying to get them off of IE11.

How do I make Waterfox delete the cookies for either a specific website or all websites after the tab/window has been closed without requiring any additional user actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click Options from the menu, then click Privacy.

Under "History\Waterfox will:"  click "remember history" and change it to "Use custom settings for history"

The last checkbox is "Clear history when Waterfox closes."

There is a settings button on the right of that option that lets you pick what you want to clear, one of the options is cookies.